# eventListener gets overridden when declared inside a method

Tags: javascript, dom, electron

I'm working on Electron app and I've hit a wall - I can't figure out how to keep multiple event listeners that came from a method of the same class active at the same time. The last listener overrides all the previous ones. There's an example at the bottom. I expect all the buttons to alert their id, while only the last declared button will do so.

Googling for past few hours gave no result. I feel like there should be an easy solution for such seemingly common problem.

Why exactly this does't work? Is there an alternative solution of storing item instances in a queue with means to manipulate its data with click events?

```js
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.list = {};
  }

  add (item) {
    this.list[item.id] = item;
  }

  remove (item) {
    delete this.list[item.id];
  }
}

class Item {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
  }

  generateHTML () {
    const hook = document.getElementById('button-hook');
    hook.innerHTML += `<button id="${this.id}">${this.id}</button>`;
  }

  addListener () {
    this.btn = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.doStuff);
  }

  doStuff() {
    alert(this.id);
  }
}

const queue = new Queue();

const foo = new Item('Foo');
foo.generateHTML();
foo.addListener();
queue.add(foo);

const bar = new Item('Bar');
bar.generateHTML();
bar.addListener();
queue.add(bar);

const baz = new Item('Baz');
baz.generateHTML();
baz.addListener();
queue.add(baz);
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="button-hook">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Modifying the `innerHTML` property deletes the entire HTML and rewrites it from scratch. As such, you're deleting every element, and re-creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the innerHTML like this

```
hook.innerHTML += `<button id="${this.id}">${this.id}</button>`;
```

It erasing anything attached to the elements. So that means you are clearing all of the event handlers attached.

You should be appending elements to the DOM

```
const button = document.createElement("button")
button.id = this.id
button.textContent = this.id
hook.appendChild(button)
```